# django template inheritance: how to NOT display a block from parent template?

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2, template-inheritance

how can we hide a block in child template which is being rendered by paent template?

for ex: my parent template
`base.html` contains-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
....
<body>
{% block messages %}
      <div class="alert alert-{% if message.tags == 'error'%}danger{% else %}{{ message.tags }}{% endif %} alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
             {{message}}
      </div>
{% endblock %}
...
</body>
</html>
```

and I have inherited this `base.html` in `login.html`
but I do not want to use {% block messages %} in `login.html`,
any suggestions?
Thanks in advance for any solution.

Comment: thanks Nikita Zhuikov, for the solution




{% block messages %}{% endblock %}
...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may override `{% block messages %}` in your login.html, like that:

login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block messages %}{% endblock %}
...
```

Comment: sorry but that didn't work, I am still able to view `base`  `messages block` in the 'login.html` , any other solution, please?

Comment: Actually I can't understand why this solution dosen't work for you, may you display code of your login.html?

Comment: thanks Nikita Zhuikov, 
 actually I the `base.html` was including the `messages block` from another file as `{% include 'partials/_topbar_navigation.html' %}`,
I moved the messages block to `base.html` . Now it is working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, it is a better practice to have a base for login and registration which is different from your application base especially if you need users to login as alot of stuff won't show on these pages like the navbar.

Comment: thank you very much @Mohamed ElKalioby for your suggestion, will remember that ,